# Bash script to filter contents of a file

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file that looks like:

```
Location1 Person1 []
Location1 Person1 [place1, place2]
Location2 Person1 [place1]
```

I want the output to be:

```
 Location1 Person1 [place1, place2]
 Location2 Person1 [place1]
```

Means I want to tell awk (or any other tool), that for a unique key Location and Person, if there are 2 entires, take the entry that has something in brackets.

Currently i am doing this, but its not helping

```
awk '!seen[$1$2]++' $FileName > temp.txt
```

Comment: What do you mean by "take" in "take the entry that has something in brackets" ? In your example `Location2 Person1 [place1]` has one entry in brackets, and it also belongs to the desired output even though you specified "if there are 2 entries".

Comment: Don't add `...`s in your sample input as they only clutter it - just make your files concise, representative, and something we can test a potential solution against. What if there are 2 entries that have something in brackets for the same key pair?

Comment: @RanyAlbegWein, Location2 belongs as the unique key is Location2 and Person1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take it easy, you don't need `awk` for that!

```
sort -r file | sort -t" " -k1,2 -u
```

Gives you:

```
Location1 Person1 [place1, place2]
Location2 Person1 [place1]
```

My assumption is that you can't have several entries with values within brackets for the same person at the same location.

Explanation:

- -r: reverse
- -t: column separator
- -k: key fields
- -u: unique

Sort with unique switch always keeps the first instance of a duplicate row. If you want to keep the last instance (here the row with the lower sorting order, which is the one including a value within brackets), you have to sort the data in reverse order before feeding them into your unique sort.

Comment: That also assumes that the first character within the square brackets will always come after (or is it before?) `]` when sorted.

Comment: @EdMorton True! But again, we are bound by the data sample provided here. I assumed that places have names starting with alphabet characters.

Comment: @retrography, Damn, so simple, why did not I think of that.

Answer (score 2):

This might be what you want:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/[[][^]]+[]]/ { print; printed[$1,$2]; next }
{ saved[$1,$2] = $0 }
END {
    for (key in saved) {
        if ( !(key in printed) ) {
                print saved[key]
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
Location1 Person1 [place1, place2]
Location2 Person1 [place1]
```

It just depends on your requirements and input samples you haven't shared with us yet.

Answer (score 0):

alternative `awk` to print the highest number of values for each unique key

```
$ awk '{k=$1 FS $2} (k in v){n=split($0,t,",")}
           !(k in v)||n>c[k]{c[k]=n; v[k]=$0}
                         END{for(k in v) print v[k]}' file

Location1 Person1 [place1, place2]
Location2 Person1 [place1]
```

in case of a tie, this will print the first line (change `n>c[k]` to `n>=c[k]` for the last)